# virtual wxlistctrl from wxGlade

Tags: wxwidgets, wxglade

I'm being a bit dense. Using wxGlade to create the layout. I need a wxListCtrl that must be virtual. When I select wxLC_VIRTUAL the resulting code is only

```
        self.all_matches_list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel_4, wx.ID_ANY, style=wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VIRTUAL | wx.LC_VRULES)
    sizer_3.Add(self.all_matches_list, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
```

What I'm not understanding is how to get that into a class where I can override the OnGetItemText function to put my data in. Also there doesn't appear to be any code that creates the columns and such, it's all disappeared when I select VIRTUAL.

I understand I could do this all manually, but I'm trying to not touch the code created by wxGlade so that I don't reedit things and forget to do something...

Comment: you may try to send an e-mail to wxglade mailing list. What version of wxGlade do you use and what wxPython version?

Comment: wxGlade 1.0.3 and wxPython 4.1.1. I'll try the mailing list